# PyCharm Unable to Install Packages

Tags: python, python-3.x, pycharm, anaconda, package

I have been trying to install Keras on my PyCharm.
I prefer `conda install` over `pip install` for installing packages in Anaconda.
After installing the package using `conda install`, I tried importing Keras using `import keras` in PyCharm.
A modulenotfound error popped up, so I tried to install keras using package manager in PyCharm, there it showed that Keras was still not installed, so I installed keras from there, and after numerous amount of attempts, the installation is not working.

As evident from the screenshot, it's stuck at this point, usually, this Background task automatically completes, but in case of Keras, it's just stuck there. It is important to mention that same happens with keras-base.

I searched about it over the Internet but it seems that not a number of people have encountered this (I might be wrong) but can someone help me here?

Edit - 1: Keras is now working by calling it via `Tensorflow` module.
Although there still are problems with PyCharm.

[image]

Comment: Why do you want to use `keras` and not `tensorflow.keras`?

Comment: @SusmitAgrawal Thanks for this tip, I can call  Keras now using that. But can you also tell me whats wrong with PyCharm here? Is this an issue of thread blockage?

Comment: What's the version of Python that you're using?

Comment: Python version - 3.7.3